# Can I use Callkit SDK to setup a call to a SIP URI

Tags: ios, sip, callkit

I'm wondering if it is possible to dial out a SIP URI from iOS Callkit. I can not find anything about this and what I tried does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any SIP Library, you can make the call but using SIP URI alone, you can not make any call using callkit.

From apple doc

> "CallKit lets you integrate your calling services with other
>   call-related apps on the system. CallKit provides the calling
>   interface, and you handle the back-end communication with your VoIP
>   service. For incoming and outgoing calls, CallKit displays the same
>   interfaces as the Phone app, giving your app a more native look and
>   feel"

For all the sip functions, you have to call the respective callkit functions to communicate with the native phone UI.
For ex.: if the caller disconnects the call, you will call sip_hangup function, at the same time you have to call the disconnect function of the callkit as well.

Comment: Ah so the Callkit is purely to give the same UI look and feel but the implementation of connecting to the VOIP service needs to be implemented with other SDKs?

Comment: Yes. Other SDKs needs to be implemented for the functionality.